# Time-based email alerts for new Opportunity after Lead conversion not working

Tags: workflow, process-builder, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

I need email alerts to go out in 3 time intervals after a Lead is converted to an Opportunity (with mapped "Submission_Id__c" <> NULL).  For example...

- If after one hour an Opportunity is in "Open" status and the "Finished" checkbox is still null, then send a "Please Finish" alert to the Opportunity contact.
- If after one day an Opportunity is in "Open" status and the "All Contacts Verified" checkbox is still null, then send a "Please Verify Contacts" alert to all Account contacts.

Nothing I've tried seems to work for this scenario.  The problems I'm having are...

**With Process Builder**

- The criteria for Opportunity creation is Submission_Id__c <> NULL.  However, the create process never fires because Submission_Id__c has apparently not been mapped yet.  It seems from my research that this is due to order of operations in the Lead conversion process (Opportunity is created before Lead is actually converted...?).
- I can't trigger off of Lead conversion because you need a record "create" event to schedule actions.

**With Workflow Rules**

- Workflow rules do actually run after Lead conversion (because Submission_Id__c is not NULL).  I can test this this because I added timestamp fields in the Opportunity for each event.  Each field gets timestamped at the expected time.
- I cannot use an Email Alert "action" in my workflow, however, because I need it to evaluate unique criteria for each alert.  You can't put criteria on a time-based action.
- If I try to trigger off the timestamp fields changing, no email alerts are sent.  Apparently, time-based actions do not count as a record update (at least, not at the time specified).
- Note that if I manually change a timestamp field in Opportunity and save, email alerts are sent out as expected.  The disconnect seems to be due to the time-based timestamp change not counting as an "update".

I'm kind of at my wit's end here.  Can anyone suggest a valid way to send out these time-based, criteria-based emails from a Lead conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.  I guess I figured this out.  The one piece where I was confused was the Submission_Id__c field mapping from Lead.  The conversion is triggered by an external application which was causing some issues populating the field.  That is now resolved.

My eventual solution was:

- Create an "Opportunity Process" (on create only) to create the scheduled tasks.
- The scheduled tasks call individual invokable processes to send the email alerts.
- The invokable processes evaluate the criteria and sends the email, if criteria are met.

There may be some other, better solution but this worked for me.